# Do cron jobs run non-interactive, non-login shells?

Tags: shell, cron, init

Say I create a `cron` job that runs a Zsh or Bash script as `/path/to/shell_script.sh`

Would such a shell be a `non-interactive` `non-login` shell?  If so, what shell `init` files would be executed (for Bash & Zsh)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zsh` sources `.zshenv` ([source](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_3.html)).

`bash` sources `$BASH_ENV` if set. ([source](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files))